# What happens to the PCB of processes that have finished their execution?

Tags: process, operating-system, controls, block

Are they removed from memory or they are maintained in memory? If they are in memory, what is the purpose?

Answer (score 0):

The PCB (process context block) holds the register state for the process (thread). It is one of many data structures an operating system maintains for a process. The PCB serves no purpose once the process is terminated so it is typically freed or reused by another process (or thread). Most other data structures are are freed or reused as well.